# Changing dynamically table IDs

Tags: javascript, html

**Context**
I am working on a football league table. I want it to be updated automatically, so I added some functions with a button that edits the team table data. Here is my main function, that decides depending of the goals written if the match was a loss, a won or a draw:

```
function PlayMatch()
        {
            /* We get scored and conceded goals */
            var scored = document.getElementById("scored").value;
            var conceded = document.getElementById("conceded").value;
            var error = document.getElementById("error_filling");

            /* We get sure that both fields are filled */
            if ((scored == "") || (conceded == ""))
            {
                /* Show error message */
                if (error.style.display === "none")
                {
                    error.style.display = "block";
                }
                else
                {
                    error.style.display = "block";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                /* Hide error message */
                if (error.style.display === "block")
                {
                    error.style.display = "none";
                }
                else
                {
                    error.style.display = "none";
                }

                /* We compare and decide if the match was a won, a draw or a lost */
                if (scored > conceded)
                {
                    Won();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (scored == conceded)
                    {
                        Draw();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (scored < conceded)
                        {
                            Lost();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The Won, Draw and Lost functions are used to change team data on the table. At the end of each one of those 3 functions a function named Count is called, to change the on favour goals, the against goals and the goals difference on the table. I do not show any of their codes because I know they work and this question will be so long.
Here are the codes corresponding to the team data updater, which includes a hidden error message used on the PlayMatch function:

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Malaga CF</legend>

        <button onclick="PlayMatch()">Play Match</button>

        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

        <div id="error_filling" style="display:none; color:red; font-family:Impact">Both fields must be filled!</div>

        <br><br>

        Scored goals<input type="text" id="scored" size="2">

        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

        Conceded goals<input type="text" id="conceded" size="2">
    </fieldset>
```

Finally, here is the league table:

```
<div id="DIV_league_table" align="left" style="display:block;">
        <table width="60%" border="0" style="text-align:center;">
            <tr class="top_row">
                <th width="7%">POS</th>
                <th width="35%">TEAM</th>
                <th width="7%">PLYD</th>
                <th width="7%">WON</th>
                <th width="7%">DRW</th>
                <th width="7%">LST</th>
                <th width="7%">FVR</th>
                <th width="7%">AGT</th>
                <th width="7%">GD</th>
                <th width="7%">PTS</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="promotion_row" style="background:#01DF01;">
                <td id="position">1</td>    <!-- Position -->
                <td id="team" align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/teams/malaga.png" width="15" height="15">&nbsp; Malaga CF</td>
                <td id="played">0</td>  <!-- Played matches -->
                <td id="wins">0</td>    <!-- Wins -->
                <td id="draws">0</td>   <!-- Draws -->
                <td id="loses">0</td>   <!-- Loses -->
                <td><span type="text" id="goalsInFavour">0</span></td>  <!-- Goals in Favour -->
                <td><span type="text" id="goalsAgainst">0</span></td>   <!-- Goals Against -->
                <td><span id="goalsDifference"></span></td> <!-- Goals Difference -->
                <td id="points"><b>0</b></td>   <!-- Points -->
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**Question**
Now I am planning adding 21 more teams, but if I use different tags for each team, the code will be extremely large, and I don't want that right now. This is the code that replaces the previous team data updater:

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Match simulator</legend>

        <select id="local_selector" onchange="AssignSide();">
            <option value="1">Málaga CF</option>
            <option value="2">Granada CF</option>
            <option value="3">Deportivo</option>
            <option value="4">Alcorcón</option>
            <option value="5">UD Las Palmas</option>
            <option value="6">Albacete</option>
            <option value="7">RCD Mallorca</option>
            <option value="8">Oviedo</option>
            <option value="9">Almería</option>
            <option value="10">Real Sporting</option>
            <option value="11">Elche CF</option>
            <option value="12">Osasuna</option>
            <option value="13">Numancia</option>
            <option value="14">Rayo Majadahonda</option>
            <option value="15">CD Lugo</option>
            <option value="16">Tenerife</option>
            <option value="17">Reus Deportiu</option>
            <option value="18">Zaragoza</option>
            <option value="19">Cádiz</option>
            <option value="20">Extremadura</option>
            <option value="21">Nástic</option>
            <option value="22">Córdoba</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="scored_local" size="2">
        <button onclick="JugarPartido()">Jugar Partido</button>
        <input type="text" id="conceded_visitor" size="2">
        <select id="visitor_selector" onchange="AssignSide();">
            <option value="1">Málaga CF</option>
            <option value="2">Granada CF</option>
            <option value="3">Deportivo</option>
            <option value="4">Alcorcón</option>
            <option value="5">UD Las Palmas</option>
            <option value="6">Albacete</option>
            <option value="7">RCD Mallorca</option>
            <option value="8">Oviedo</option>
            <option value="9">Almería</option>
            <option value="10">Real Sporting</option>
            <option value="11">Elche CF</option>
            <option value="12">Osasuna</option>
            <option value="13">Numancia</option>
            <option value="14">Rayo Majadahonda</option>
            <option value="15">CD Lugo</option>
            <option value="16">Tenerife</option>
            <option value="17">Reus Deportiu</option>
            <option value="18">Zaragoza</option>
            <option value="19">Cádiz</option>
            <option value="20">Extremadura</option>
            <option value="21">Nástic</option>
            <option value="22">Córdoba</option>
        </select>

        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

        <div id="error_filling" style="display:none; color:red; font-family:Impact">Both fields must be filled!</div>
    </fieldset>
```

I prefer the table to stay the same, each team with the same id "loses" for its lost games. Then, if I select for example Malaga CF in the local_selector dropdown, change its variables to "played_local", "wins_local" etc to edit them depending on the match result without editing the rest of the teams and then turning them back to "played", "wins" etc.
Is that possible? I can provide more information if needed. Sorry if I forgot to translate some part of the code (I have originally names and IDs in Spanish) or if I posted so much information, but I wanted to give as most context as possible, as those variables affects many parts of the code.

Comment: Hi Carlos! Before I dive in here, don't ever give the same id to two different items on a page. Use classes or data attributes.There is no exception to this rule and it will only damage your code and prevent things from working.

Comment: @zfrisch I had that in mind a bit. I thought at first that I could use those values in the selector to go to the <tr> of a determined team and change its variables there, because of them being in the same <tr>, but that doesn't seem to be the best way to do it